# ModuleWithProviders<T> requires 1 type argument(s) - angular-autofocus-fix

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, node-modules

After installed `angular-autofocus-fix`

imported the AutofocusModule

When i run the angular projects its shows below error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/angular-autofocus-fix/index.d.ts:4:23 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders
```

When i check in that node_mudule

[image]

I am using angular 10 in my project.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By adding this below given code snippet in `app.module.ts` fixed the issue

```
declare module "@angular/core" {
  interface ModuleWithProviders<T = any> {
    ngModule: Type<T>;
    providers?: Provider[];
  }
}

@NgModule({
  // ......
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In my case, this problem happened when I upgraded `ng-bootstrap` version in `angular-10`.

Comment: make sure to add above before the @NgModule decorator

Answer (score 1):

it seems it is not updated for Angular 10, ModuleWithProviders can no longer be used witthout generic (https://angular.io/guide/updating-to-version-10#new-removals-of-deprecated-apis)

there is an issue on the repo about it: https://github.com/korniychuk/angular-autofocus-fix/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

Please try Observable to fix this issue.